# Distributional derivative and Laplace-Beltrami operator

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, distribution-theory

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^3$ be an open, bounded and connected set with $C^2-$regular boundary $\Gamma$. Consider an arbitary test function $\phi \in C^2(\Gamma)$. If $\Delta$ here denotes the Laplace-Beltrami operator and $f \in W^{2,p}(\Gamma)$ for any $1 \le p \lt \infty$ then I'm wondering:

> Is this $\int_{\Gamma} \Delta f \phi= \int_{\Gamma} f \Delta \phi$
>   valid **in the sense of distributions**? And if yes, could someone
>   provide a detailed explanation?

Disclaimer: I'm mostly familiar to distributions in $\mathbb R$ and is the first time I handle with the Laplace-Beltrami operator. Thus what I'm asking may be probably silly or elementary but I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't have enough regularity for $\Delta f$ to be defined on $\Gamma$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. What if $f \in \mathcal M_{+}(\Gamma)$? Would $\Delta f$ then be defined?

Comment: What is $\cal{M}_+$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. of course,excuse me... the space of positive measures

Comment: The issue is how you are definining the distributional Laplacian of $f$. You may *define*  $\langle \Delta f,\phi \rangle = \int_{\Gamma} f \Delta \phi$ but this is not generally reprentable by integration over $\Gamma$, whether $f$ belongs to $W^{2,p}$ or defines a positive measure on $\Gamma$.